# ctypes NULL-terminated array

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I want to wrap a dll library in my python code using ctypes. I'd like to feed in an NULL-terminated array of NULL-terminated strings. In my python code, the a ctype array is initiated by

```
L = ['foo','bar', None] # to get a NULL terminated array
arr = (ctypes.c_char_p * 3)(*L)
lib.myfunc(None, arr)
```

In myfunc.c, I have

```
void myfunc(char* p1, char** p2){
    printf("%p\n", (void *) p1);

    printf("%s\n", *p2);p2++;
    printf("%s\n", *p2);p2++;
    printf("%p\n", (void *) p2);
}
```

If I run the python code, I get

```
(nil)
foo
bar
0x1eb8150
```

which means that the first pointer (which is None) is correctly recognized as a NULL pointer. But the third (last) item pointed to by p2 is not a NULL.

What's wrong in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last statement prints `p2` itself. (pointer to pointer).

You should dereference `p2` like statements before the last one.

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) *p2);
```